# Using Thunderbird and Outlook with GMail

Tags: thunderbird

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this, but since I thought it might be a Thunderbird setting, I posted here.

I have set up both Thunderbird (on Ubuntu 11.10) and Outlook (on Windows 7) to download my gmail emails. Whenever Thunderbird downloads a mail (which hasn't been downloaded by Outlook), Outlook won't download that mail. The mail hasn't been deleted from the server, because I can still see it using the GMail browser app, but it seems like it's marked as "downloaded" and therefore Outlook doesn't want to grab it. Is there a setting to disable this functionality in Thunderbird, or is this something I need to enable in Outlook?

Comment: are you using pop3 in outlook?

Comment: I'm using POP3 for both systems

Comment: That explains it all. Use IMAP.

Comment: If I use IMAP, will it still download my emails? Or will it require an internet connection every time I want to view?

Comment: Yeah it will download em. I use it in Thunderbird.

Comment: That's great. Exactly what I want. When setting up the account in Thunderbird, the text is a little misleading (IMAP: remote folders; POP3: keep mail on your computer) which is probably why I had this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use IMAP to avoid this problem, because with POP3, it marks the message as "read" and essentially will not pass it on to other clients.

Comment: See also: "Synchronization & Storage" under "account settings" -- you can fine tune the rules about what is stored locally for access when you aren't connected to the internet.